# How to create pandas dataframe without rounding long values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the sample:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1706121660, 1.152229705572702e-06, 1.074741466619169e-06, 1.074741466619169e-06, 1.074741466619169e-06, 0.28], [1706121600, 1.125333298543622e-06, 1.157527924446797e-06, 1.088866832550798e-06, 1.152229705572702e-06, 4.681397952]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I see this result:

```
    0           1           2           3           4           5
0   1706121660  0.000001    0.000001    0.000001    0.000001    0.280000
1   1706121600  0.000001    0.000001    0.000001    0.000001    4.681398
```

How can I see the real values without rounding in the result? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase precision via

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.20f}'.format)
```

In your example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your values are not rounded, they just **looks like** they are:

```
df.loc[0, 1]
# 1.152229705572702e-06
```

You could change the display format to see them with a scientific notation:

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:g}'.format):
    # jupyter notebook
    display(df)
    # or with print
    print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
            0           1           2           3           4      5
0  1706121660 1.15223e-06 1.07474e-06 1.07474e-06 1.07474e-06   0.28
1  1706121600 1.12533e-06 1.15753e-06 1.08887e-06 1.15223e-06 4.6814
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Your data
data = [[1706121660, 1.152229705572702e-06, 1.074741466619169e-06, 1.074741466619169e-06, 1.074741466619169e-06, 0.28],
        [1706121600, 1.125333298543622e-06, 1.157527924446797e-06, 1.088866832550798e-06, 1.152229705572702e-06, 4.681397952]]

# Creating DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Set the display precision to show all decimal places
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.20f' % x)

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Ask your question ChatGPT. You will get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the display precision of by the pd.set_option() function.
E.g.:

```
pd.set_option('precision', 60)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option